# Retrieving result from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

As I know so far, we can use

```
$result = $query->row_array();
```

to retrieve the single value from the database and

```
$result = $query->result_array();
```

to retrieve multiple values from the database.

In this case I am using the particular table `CRUD` options. So instead of writing

```
$rows = $query->num_rows();
if( $rows > 1 ){
    $result = $query->result_array();
}
if( $rows == 1 ){
    $result = $query->row_array();
}
```

Is there any other way to write the query even if the table has only a single row or multiple row?

Please guide me. Thanks in advance friends

Comment: not clear what you want

Comment: @PathikVejani :  In my table i may have a single row or multiple rows . I should write only one query so that it should fetch if it has only single rows or multiple rows . instead of using the num rows after the result spliting the result array into two if it has onl one row do row_array() or perform result_array();

Comment: you have to count the result then perform other operation

Comment: @PathikVejani: No other option yeah !

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
   {
      echo $row->title;
      echo $row->name;
      echo $row->body;
   }
}
```

if you want check one row or multiple row

```
 $query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
       {
          echo $row->title;
          echo $row->name;
          echo $row->body;
       }
    }else if($query->num_rows() > 1){
       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
       {
          echo $row->title;
          echo $row->name;
          echo $row->body;
       }
}else{
    echo 'No any records in data base';
}
```

it's doesn't matter one record or more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    return $query->result();
}else{
    return false;
}
```